# Don't set session method post with https in rails 5.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session

I don't understand when I login with http session run normal and login success, but when I use https I can't set session and login fails.

I find solution add `config.force_ssl = true` in file 'config/production.rb' but login fails with https.

Comment: Have you got any error from the log?

Comment: Thank you!  I see: HTTP Origin header [https://mydomain](https://mydomain) didn't match request.base_url [http://mydomain](http://mydomain), I will find the cause here

Comment: I see resolve here: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/22965